# Is this possible to roughly estimate when next N blocks will be generated from now?

Tags: block-interval, height

I have a lightning node running locally. For some events in the future (e.g. when a pending channel will be closed) it shows such values: `"blocks_til_maturity": 107`.

It means that when block height reaches `current_block_height + 107`, the event occurs.

So, having current block height and desired height, how can I roughly estimate the time needed to reach that height?

Answer (score 2):

The mining process results in an expected block interval of ten minutes. If you only need a rough estimate, you can therefore simply calculate it by `blocks_til_maturity × 10 minutes`.